# "Never say die?"

Tags: etymology, idioms

What's the deal with this idiom? I know what it means, but cannot wrap my head around its <s>grammar</s> structure. The sentence structure of

> "Never say die"

looks like that of

> "Never admit defeat"

but it does not make the same grammatical+semantical sense.

Is it an archaic use? Is it a contraction of a longer phrase? Was it originally misspoken by someone of note and survived memetically? What are its roots?

Edit: Well, the comments made me realize that I worded my question poorly. I'm not saying I think this phrase is ungrammatical. I'm asking how the heck "saying 'die'" came to mean what it means.

Comment: I believe that, apart from some obvious punctuation, this is not grammatically incorrect. Never say, “die”.

Comment: @Ishmaeel Please identify the grammatical problem you see in the phrase.

Comment: @MrLister I've never seen the phrase punctuated any differently from how the OP presented it (that is, none at all).

Comment: @ΜετάEd: I already illustrated my perceived problem with the comparison in blockquotes. "Never admit defeat" is a complete, imperative sentence. The other does not seem to be, unless you enquote "die" as suggested by Mr Lister. And if "die" is quoted, the problem becomes semantic and the phrase evokes an image of a comic strip where a stick figure says only "die" in his speech balloon and others scold him for giving up. Why would he say "die?" Why wouldn't he say "I'm dead?"

Comment: @Ishmaeel ehm, if he was still alive, saying "I'm dead" technically wouldn't be correct. And if he was dead, he wouldn't be able to say it.

Comment: @MrLister, well, he would be saying it metaphorically, as in Austin Powers would say "I'm spent", when he wouldn't really be complaining about having been used as legal tender in a monetary transaction. He would mean "Well, that's it, I'm good as dead, I won't pursue this matter anymore." But no. Instead, he says "die", which is an imperative to the person he is addressing. Why would the listener die, if the speaker is the one who is losing hope?

Comment: With the acceptability of reduced that-clauses, report structures are permitted without the _that_: Never say [that] you're beaten. Never admit you're defeated. This is productive: Never wish a vagabond "Merry Christmas." Never wish a vagabond (a) merry Christmas. Never say hello to a stranger carrying a sub-machine gun. However, the frozen expression _Never say die_ , as the fine answers say, predates this trend - possibly even started it. The closest productive usage may be _Never say Never Again_ .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression ["never say die"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22file%20an%20appeal%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22never%20say%20die%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YqdhUP_EG6iT0QX8iICABA&ved=0CCYQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1700,cd_max:31/12/1820&tbm=bks&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=46810cf96877f311&biw=1371&bih=886) has been around since at least the early 1800s, but I think OP is attempting to over-analyse the grammar.

It just means *don't use the word "die"* (as in *"We're all going to die!"*) because that would imply you've given up hope, which might become a [self-fulfilling prophecy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4274/what-word-means-to-speak-something-into-existence). It's much the same as ["Where there's life there's hope"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22file%20an%20appeal%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22where%20there%27s%20life%20there%27s%20hope%22&hl=en&tbm=bks&tbas=0&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=jalhUOSqBeKA0AX62IDoCA&ved=0CCIQpwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=46810cf96877f311&biw=1371&bih=886)

---

As [@Edwin comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83724/never-say-die/83737#comment166513_83724), there's also *Never say never*. Add to that a couple of thousand written instances of [*Never say can't*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22never%20say%20can%27t%22) (and a couple of dozen [*Never say hopeless*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22never%20say%20hopeless%22), for example) and I think one could reasonably say this is a "productive" construction even today.

Comment: One vote for "contraction." Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

According to *Concise Oxford English Dictionary*, one says “*never say die* … to encourage someone not to give up hope”.

It functions literally as a reply to a statement such as “we are all going to *die*”, expressing hopelessness in the face of a deadly situation.

It is also used idiomatically as a reply to similar statements of hopelessness not containing the word *die*, or when the speaker anticipates such a statement and wants to forestall it, or when the speaker is struggling with feelings of hopelessness and wants to banish them.

The *earliest* published example I found is from “The-Man-of-War’s-Man, Chapter XVI” (evidently part of a novel serialization) printed in *Blackwood’s Magazine, Volume 18* (1825):

> Cheer up then, and *never say die*, for the devil a morsel of good it will do.

To uncover *more* examples, you can use the *Google Ngram Viewer*: [search for](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=never%20say%20die,Never%20say%20die&year_start=1&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0) `[ never say die,Never say die ]`; click through the various date ranges beneath the chart to view the source texts using *Google Book Search*.

Comment: Judging from that one page, the text is full of archaic forms and informal speech. Some lines contain a verse-like quality. So this one seems to count as a vote for "deliberate misuse with artistic license in younger days," yes?

Comment: @Ishmaeel Not sure what you are asking. Maybe you can answer your own question by looking at more examples. Try the Google Ngram Viewer: search for `[ Never say die, never say die ]` and set your date brackets for 1800 to 1900.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it is a strange construction. So I thought maybe searching for why you might use the phrase "say die" (instead of "never say die") might shed some light on the origin of the phrase. The earliest publication I could find, in which the phrase "say die" was included, is a play called, "The Faithful Shepherd." The play was published in 1590, written in Italian by [Giovanni Battista Guarini.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Battista_Guarini) The English translation wasn't published until 1647. In a 1736 edition of a book entitled *The faithful shepherd:
A pastoral tragi-comedy, written in Italian by the celebrated Signor Baptista Guarini*, there are these lines [(pages 102 and 103)](http://books.google.com/books?id=JgsJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=%22say+die%22&source=bl&ots=XH2VAnQ109&sig=2j5hurMQkv-V276IxhZVO9cJJss&hl=en&sa=X&ei=l6xhUOj2IIff0gG9lICIAQ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22say%20die%22&f=false):

> "Let those fair amiable Eyes release
>
> My Life, now bitter, which once made it sweet;
>
> And those bright Stars, which my Love's Torches li't,
>
> Light too my Funeral Tapers, and fore-run,
>
> As once my rising, now my setting Sun.
>
> But thou more hard than 'ere thou wert before,
>
> Feel'st yet no Spark of Pity, but art more
>
> Deaf to my Pray'rs. Must I then talk alone?
>
> Wretch that I am, discourse I to a Stone!
>
> **Say die,** at least, if nothing else thou' It say,
>
> And thou shalt see me die..."

Within the next century, for whatever reason, the phrase "Never say die." becomes quite common. (I'm not saying it's a result of the play, by any means, in case anyone mistakenly thinks I'm implying that.) MetaEd mentions one citation in his answer, but there are many citations from the 1800s in which the phrase is used, including a flowery poem attributed to J.F. Waller, reprinted in [Oddfellows' magazine](http://books.google.com/books?id=giEZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=%22never+say+die%22+oddfellows&source=bl&ots=dv7wpIS5ZV&sig=vIv-p4ZKxPWjyHXcS-4qcYl-pXo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=J6lhUIasKtS50AHkwoDgAg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22never%20say%20die%22%20oddfellows&f=false), Vol. 13, 1881, page 91:

> Never say die—never say die;
>
> Life's worth the living, if we only try;
>
> The hand and the brain
>
> Were not given in vain.
>
> We've a battle to gain,
>
> And so—never say die.
>
> Never say die—never say die;
>
> If earnings be low and if living be high,
>
> 'Tis reason the more
>
> Not to faint or give o'er,
>
> Better days are in store,
>
> And so—never say die.
>
> Never say die—never say die—
>
> When night is at darkest the morning is nigh;
>
> Whether far off or near,
>
> In God's time will appear
>
> Some blessing to cheer,
>
> And so never say die.
>
> Never say die—never say die;
>
> The soul that is steadfast may fortune defy;
>
> In labour and art
>
> Let the hand and the heart
>
> Each do its own part,
>
> And so—never say die.
>
> Never say die—never say die;
>
> When cowards despair, be this our reply—
>
> All that's noble and human
>
> In constant and true man,
>
> In brave patient woman,
>
> Cries—never say die.
>
> Never say die—never say die;
>
> Life is God's gift that we may not lay by;
>
> Whatever befall,
>
> 'Tis the duty of all'
>
> Till he gives the call
>
> To say—never say die.

Comment: I don't think the usage in the play has anything to do with this phrase. There, it is simply used as an imperative: "Say die" = "ask me to die (which I will)". But the poem certainly looks like it could boost an ordinary phrase into idiomhood. So one vote for "irregular use with poetic license?" Thanks.