# Never say die...?

Tags: slang

What does it mean never say die? I've heard many times the phrase: "Never say die" But I don't know exactly for what it's used. Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/never+say+die

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83724/never-say-die