# Term for subconsciously assuming something to be true just because it is noted down somewhere

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a term referring to the tendency of a person to believe something to be true simply because it is noted down somewhere?

By noted down I mean either written down in real life or on the internet, but also broadcasted on TV or included in any other form of media.

My first thoughts were [belief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief_bias) and [confirmation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) bias, but I feel like neither of those terms match what I'm looking for. The closest I got to an answer is this question, [Term for the sense that something must be true because many people talk about it](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95130/term-for-the-sense-that-something-must-be-true-because-many-people-talk-about-it), which I found on this site, but what I'm looking for is focused more on a single person, not considering the society as a whole.

To describe it in another way, I'm looking for a term which would describe a person neglecting to check the validity of a fact, not because they trust the source of the fact, but simply because they are tired or their mind is somehow occupied with something else.

Comment: I'd call this "unconscious reverence for the written word."  But of course that's far more than one written word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a special case of the [argument from authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest **"gullibility"**(noun) and **"gullible"** (adj)

> - [**gullible**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gullible) (adj) - quick to believe something that is not true.
> - [**gullibility**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gullibility) (noun) -  tendency to believe too readily and therefore to be easily deceived.

Now, if the person is too lazy to check the veracity of what he's read or been told by an unreliable source, I would say he is **careless** or even **reckless**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this captures your intended meaning, but the word "[suggestibility](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/suggestibility)" comes to mind.

Comment: Suggestibility is similar to what I'm looking for, but not it. I've edited the question with a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**faith** also *unquestioning faith* and *blind faith*

faith
feɪθ
noun
1.
complete trust or confidence in someone or something.
"this restores one's faith in politicians"
synonyms:   trust, belief, confidence, conviction, credence, reliance, dependence;

2.
strong belief in the doctrines of a religion, based on spiritual conviction rather than proof.

https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=faith+meaning

Answer (score 0):

**acceptation**

> : belief; acceptance as true or valid. [Random-House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/acceptation)

**accept/take at face value**

> : to accept something exactly the way it appears to be. I don't know
>   whether I can take her story at face value, but I will assume that she
>   is not lying. The committee took the report at face value and approved
>   the suggested changes [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+at+face+value)
>
> Something that is **taken/accepted at face value** is regarded as true or
>   genuine without being questioned or doubted. [M-W](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/face%20value)

.

Answer (score 0):

"Gullibility" (answered by @Centaurus) is a failure of social intelligence in which a person is easily tricked or manipulated into an ill-advised course of action.

It is closely related to **credulity**, which is the tendency to believe unlikely propositions that are unsupported by evidence.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullibility)

*EDIT: beaten on the wire by Centaurus for "gullibility"*.

Answer (score 0):

The word "scripturalist" comes to mind, but that is specific to religion. You are looking for a word that means something like "secular scripturalist".
The word "authoritative" means "backed up by a reliable source" (which is usually a written source these days), but I don't think "authoritativist" is a word, unfortunately.
I also thought of "textualist", but that's mostly used specifically in the legal sphere.
A "logolator" is someone with an excessive respect for words.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a technical term in pragmatics: ***Presupposition***. A proposition A (any statement, essentially) is said to be *presupposed* by some other proposition B if it is necessary to believe B in order to understand A. This is different from simply **asserting** some proposition. For instance (see more in [Fillmore's "Verbs of Judging"](https://www.google.com/search?q=fillmore%20verbs%20judging)),

- *Bill's brother is visiting him*
  **presupposes** *Bill has a brother*
  and **asserts** that his brother is visiting Bill.
- *Bill accused Mary of doing it*
  presupposes that "doing it" was wrong,
  and asserts that Bill claimed Mary did it.
- *Bill criticized Mary for doing it*
  presupposes that Mary did it,
  and asserts that Bill believes "doing it" was wrong.

Presupposition is one of the various semantic/pragmatic relations between propositions that language makes possible. [It's a very complex topic, as this undergraduate handout on the subject of presuppositions and entailments makes clear](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/presuptrig.pdf).