# Term for an explanation that seems plausible simply because it's more complex than a more widely accepted belief

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I was recently on a lengthy flight and was pondering the regulations on cell phone usage.  I've heard that the cell phone doesn't actually interfere with the plane's flight systems (or comms, or anything at all) but that one of the reasons for the "airplane mode" requirement is that A) the phone generally just won't be able to get a signal anyway, and B) if it *can* reach a tower, it's expensive (computationally) for the cell network to hand-off a phone that's jumping from one tower to another at 500 MPH.  Multiply this by a cockpit full of passengers, and it's a big load on the system.  This seemed fairly plausible to me, but I wondered if that was only because it was a more complex/technical answer than the more accepted "it messes with the plane" answer.  **Is there a term for an explanation which seems like it might be the *real* reason for something, simply because it's more complicated than the more widely accepted explanation?**

It's almost the opposite of [Argumentum ad populum](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/95130/140899).

NOTE: I suppose that it *is* possible that I'm the only one on the planet susceptible to this phenomenon...

Comment: Is it the anti-Occam's Razor rule, or "If you can't dazzle them with brilliance, baffle them with BS"?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bizarreness_effect

Comment: Consider the possibility that it's not the complexity, but the [*causal explanation*](http://www.blackwellreference.com/public/tocnode?id=g9781405106795_chunk_g97814051067954_ss1-44) that you prefer. There is some research suggesting that [simpler explanations are preferred even by children](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/dev/48/4/1156/), but that [complex explanations take the upper hand when supported unambiguously by probability information](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010028506000739).

Comment: My answer-in-comments above challenges your premise so it doesn't really answer the question you posed. But if you like it, ping me and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: It does look like you're asking a question about cognitive science or something similar. I'm not so sure that the fact that you're looking for an _English_ term is good enough for this site. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Lawrence, I haven't had a chance to read the [paper you linked to](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ad63/253862c3fca52f6659d32582aa11d3d2cee0.pdf) yet, but i'm intrigued by what seems to be an experimental investigation of Occam's Razor.  In the particular example I gave above, one could say that "cell phones interfere with the planes electronics" is a causal explanation as well, so I'm not sure that's it... Maybe it's easier to question a simple statement than a more complex one... or maybe I'm just a contrarian (I suspect the folks I work with wouldn't disagree).

Comment: @Keepthesemind I was hoping that it wouldn't really turn into a discussion of the cognitive science (also hoping to avoid a cell-phones-on-airplanes discussion) but looking for a way to express the idea behind it.  Maybe it's a less common phenomenon than I imagined, however.

Comment: @AC I suppose the issue is that even if cell phones interfered with the plane's electronics, the causal link of that interference isn't spelt out.

Comment: It is perhaps a version of the "conjunction fallacy," the assumption that more specific conditions are more probable than general ones. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_fallacy

Comment: @Keepthesemind, I agree that the OP may have better luck w/ this on the philosophy SE, but I don't understand your "there's no conjunction here." In the "B" explanation there obviously is, technically. It could be rewritten more formally to make that even more clear. But generally it seems to operate via the same representativeness heuristic. OP will assume a technical cause and the misleading vividness of a more complex technical explanation is presumptively more representative. A person is not going to make a separate evaluation of each technical aspect but, rather, a joint one of the whole.

Comment: @MDHunter I retracted my remark on the lack of conjunction. It is just that the evidence (the empirical test) for such fallacy traditionally involves an answer 1 and an answer 2 that is a conjunction of answer 1 and something else. Here (in the question above), the answers (plane interference vs tower difficulties) are not overlapping. Long story: I agree with you.

Comment: Is 'snob appeal' a fancy enough answer?

Comment: I suspect that the idea  that cell phones  mess with the plane is so utterly incredible that any alternative seems more acceptable.  What would be the point of all the airport security if a terrorist had simply to adjust his cell phone and down might come  the plane?

Comment: Another example of a phenomenon where the real answer is more complex than the commonly given/preferred explanation is "what causes economic downturns and job losses?" The simplistic/populist answer is "teh immigrantz"; the real answer is much more complicated and involves capitalism, globalisation, investments, balance of international trade, budget deficits, etc.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that the more complex answer necessarily is the **right** one, just that it's somehow more convincing when neither side brings any definitive evidence to the table.  I'm starting to think that the conjunction fallacy does come into play a bit, or at least both have similar psychological roots.  In any case, I was hoping to find a term that describes the phenomenon, idiomatically, scientifically, or anywhere in between.  It looks like I may need to give up and move over to Philosophy SE (or Cognitive Sciences, perhaps)

Comment: I think there's rhetoric at play as well. When the argument is either A or B i.e. Do electronics interfere with planes? And the answer provided says no its not an a or b relationship it's C - this is taxing on the mind - a phenomenon known as cognitive dissonance - and might aid your belief

Comment: EMI/EMC is not a precise science with how many variables come into play, so rather than risk it the airlines want to minimiz(s)e it

Comment: From the novel "1984" we have "bafflegab."

Comment: Bafflegab: the professional logorrhoea of many politicians, officials and salespeople, characterized by prolix abstract circumlocution and/or a profusion of abstruse technical terminology, used as a means of persuasion, pacification or obfuscation

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like *ignoratio elenchi*, or missing the point.  Since your
specific example substitutes misdirection for a candid answer, it is
purposefully missing the point.

To the question “Why turn off cell phones?” the answer “It interferes with
the plane and so is potentially dangerous” is false, and knowingly so,
but that is the correct answer to “Why can’t I fire a gun in the plane,”
so it is a right answer to a different question.

What isn’t directly to your point is about simplicity trumping complexity
in that the candid answer would take more effort or would be more
subject to debate or more difficult to understand than using a lie to
cultivate the inference that if you use a cell phone everyone would die
in a plane crash.

So the implicit intimidation behind the simple answer is a manipulation
which uses fear rather than reason to gain acquiescence.  So one question
would be “Is the answer to the question true or false?”  If true, it is
not *ignoratio enelchi* in any case.  Using a simple true answer, with
more extensive justifications behind it, would simply be a simplification.

In your example it is false. A further question might be “Is the simple
answer manipulative, or based on fear, or just wrong?” The airline
might have a motive for having the flight attendant give a wrong answer,
so the term for the airline would be different than the flight attendant.

I’m not sure how specific you want your term.  I know I’m still not
exactly on point, because *ignoratio elenchi* does not address complexity,
but maybe this helps.  Probably way more writing than you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an appeal to complexity or appeal to obfuscation.

I found one external source that used the term "appeal to complexity": http://www.don-lindsay-archive.org/skeptic/arguments.html#complexity

> if the arguer doesn't understand the topic, he concludes that nobody
>   understands it. So, his opinions are as good as anybody's.

I agree -- this is something that seems commonplace to me as well.

(Nitpick: if the *cockpit* of the aircraft is full of *passengers*, ala *Airport 1975*, there are a lot of problems on that flight!)